# View doesn't send model in post-method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am new to ASP.NET and trying to create a Web UI for a project of mine.

The user should be able to edit a config file of the other application. For that reason he can select a config line from a list and gets a new form to edit the actual line.

If I then use the `POST` method to submit the result the parameter contains the default values.

The view:

```
@model Config

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Configuration";
}

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h5>Edit Config</h5>
    </div>
    <form asp-action="EditConfig" method="post">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Name">@Model.Name</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                 <div class="col form-group">
                    <input asp-for="Value" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>

        <input type="hidden" value="Type" id="Type" />
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Speichern</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The `POST` method in the controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult EditConfig(Config config)
{}
```

The model class `Config`:

```cs
public class Config
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }

    public Config(string name, object value, Type type)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
        Type = type;
    }

    public Config() : this("", "", typeof(Type)) { }
}
```

I tried to use hidden inputs but that doesn't seem to make a difference since even the `Value` property doesn't receive a value.

Is the `Type` property messing things up here?

**UPDATE**

I was able to get it somewhat working thanks to [David´s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328193/david) comment and [RG Orobia´s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76035310/21113504).
The problem seams to be the types of the properties.

The code for the view is now:

```
@model Config

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Configuration";
}

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h5>Edit Config</h5>
    </div>
    <form asp-action="EditConfig" method="post">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Name">@Model.Name</label>
                    <input hidden asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                 <div class="col form-group">
                    <input asp-for="Value" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col form-group">
                    <input hidden asp-for="Type" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Speichern</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

However the `Type` property still doesn't get the correct value, which isn't really a problem for me but i thought i still list it here.

Comment: You have `asp-for="Value"` on one input, did you simply forget the `asp-for="Type"` on the other?  In the resulting client-side code, what are the actual `<input>` elements in the browser?  What value is being entered in the `Value` input?  In your browser's debugging tools where you can observe the POST request, what key/value pairs are sent to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `Value` cannot be serialized. One workaround would be to change `Value` to type `string` and then cast the value to whatever type you want on the backend.